# How to use sudo on PHP passthru

Tags: php, cron, sudo

I want to use sudo to generate my txt file from a rtf file, it works when I'm using Putty, but does not when I'm using PHP script.

Here is my code :

```
$fichier_final = str_replace("/cron/txt/","/cron/depot_erreurs", $fichier_final);
$cmd = sprintf('unoconv -f %s -o %s %s',
    escapeshellarg($extension), escapeshellarg($fichier_final),
    escapeshellarg($path.$fichier));
$resultat = NULL;
passthru($cmd, $resultat);
```

I tried sudo before unoconv, but it not worked.
Any ideas ? Thanks

EDIT : My file.rtf that I want to change is on 777

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script will need to be run as a root user.  Obviously you shouldn't do this if this script is serving HTTP requests. But crontab is a user level service so you can add scripts to the crontab of root.

If you just need to run this in the commandline, use `sudo myscript.php`.  PHP itself wont need to execute subcommands as root.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll change both my script and my crontab